# .gg geo targeting in Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, geotargeting, cctld

I would like to buy a `.gg` domain.

Can I geo target a `.gg` domain to somewhere other than Guernsey (the country associated with `.gg`) in Google Search Console?

`.gg` is a county code top level domain. Google suggests setting your site to "Unlisted" for international traffic (if you don't want your site associated with any location, select "Unlisted").

Is this option currently present for the `.gg` domain in the Google Search Console tool?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I geo target a `.gg` domain to somewhere other than Guernsey

No. Currently, `.gg` domains are not on [Google's list of ccTLDs treated as gTLDs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en&visit_id=1-636491091315043481-1046684363&rd=1); as a result, their intrinsic geographic target can't be overridden.

> Google suggests setting your site to "Unlisted" for international traffic […]. Is this option currently present for the `.gg` domain in the Google Search Console tool?

No, for the same reason as above.